# Run a new thread Qt C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, class, qthread

i want to run code in a seperate thread of the main application, for that i hava created some file :

thread2.h

```
#ifndef THREAD2_H
#define THREAD2_H
#include <QThread>

class thread2 : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    thread2();

protected:
    void run();

};

#endif // THREAD2_H
```

thread2.cpp

```
#include "thread2.h"

thread2::thread2()
{
    //qDebug("dfd");
}
void thread2::run()
{
    int test = 0;
}
```

And the main file called main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include "thread1.cpp"
#include "thread2.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    thread2::run();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But it dosen't work...

Qt Creator tell me : "cannot call member function 'virtual void thread2::run()' without object"

Thanks !

Comment: Really good article on QThreads: [How To Really, Truly Use QThread](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Invoking it like this: `thread2::run()` is how you would call a `static` function, which `run()` is not.

Also, to start a thread you don't call the `run()` method explicitly, you need to create a thread object and call `start()` on it which should invoke your `run()` method in the appropriate thread:

```
thread2 thread;
thread.start()
...
```

Comment: Right, thanks, now i have another error : Qt creator tell me : "undefined reference to `vtable for thread2"

Comment: @RochesterFox don't you have to use the `override` keyword if you're overriding a method?

Comment: No that was an error from qt sorry its solved, i have a last question, why when i execute my application i don't see two different process in the taskmanager ??

Comment: @RochesterFox because threads don't run in separate processes, they run in the same process. However, you should see multiple threads in your process tho (the task manager has a Threads column that shows how many threads run within your process).

Comment: Threads and processes are not interchangeable. If you want separate processes you should use QProcess. Also you should note that your thread terminates at the end of your run() function, so in your case your thread runs for the amount of time it takes to 0 to your local variable and then quits.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Thread Class that allows you to pass a pointer to a function is as follows:

```
typedef struct TThread_tag{
int (*funct)(int, void*);
char* Name;
int Flags;
}TThread;

 class Thread : public QThread {
 public:
   TThread ThreadInfoParm;
   void setFunction(TThread* ThreadInfoIn) 
   {
      ThreadInfoParm.funct = ThreadInfoIn->funct;   
   }
 protected:
    void run() 
    {
      ThreadInfoParm.funct(0, 0);   
     }
    };

 TThread* ThreadInfo = (TThread*)Parameter;
 //Create the thread objedt
 Thread* thread = new Thread;
 thread->setFunction(ThreadInfo);//Set the thread info
 thread->start();  //start the thread
```